# Using ASP.NET usercontrols for templating without having a Website project?

Tags: asp.net, ascx, templating

Is there a way of using ASP.NET user-controls (.ascx files) to fill my own templating needs within a .NET application, without that application being a Website?

It's actually a class library that will take data in, combine it with a template, then spit it out.

I don't want to write my own templating system from scratch, so I'm looking to re-use ASP.NET functionality for my needs.

I was told that ASP.NET usercontrol rendering is reliant on IIS. Is there some hack or trick to make it work in a .NET class library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be useful to you...may not be exactly what you are looking for..

[Building Re-Usable ASP.NET User Control and Page Libraries with VS 2005](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/28/423888.aspx)

Also have a look at

[Turning an .ascx User Control into a Redistributable Custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure if I'm following the question properly, but if you are just looking for a templating engine you might want to check out [NVelocity](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html), which is part of the Castle Project.

It allows you to create a template like this (ripped from their getting started guide on the site):

```
From: $from
To: $to
Subject: $subject

Hello $customer.Name

We're please to yada yada yada.
```

And then propulate it like so:

```
Template template = velocity.GetTemplate(@"path/to/myfirsttemplate.vm");
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.Put("from", "somewhere");
context.Put("to", "someone");
context.Put("subject", "Welcome to NVelocity");
context.Put("customer", new Customer("John Doe") );

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
template.Merge(context, writer);
Console.WriteLine(writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Rajsh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441898/using-asp-net-usercontrols-for-templating-without-having-a-website-project#441906) I'd like to point out that there is a [web deployment project template](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx) for Visual Studio, which allows you to **precompile** .ascx files into a single assembly.

It simplifies your deployment/installation process. You don't have to copy/synchronize new ascx files, just the created DLL.

Here is a link to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx).